# meta programming in bash/zsh to reload shell script

Tags: bash, metaprogramming, zsh

I have three zsh script,

`meta_zsh.sh`,

```
# meta_zsh.sh
meta_s() {
    eval 'echo "${(%):-%x} re-define s()"; s() { echo " calling s() ${(%):-%x}"; }'
}
```

`script_zsh.sh` and `script_zsh_2.sh` (the same content)

```
# script_zsh.sh and script_zsh_2.sh (the same content)
meta_s
s
```

in zsh execute below commands

```
$ . ./meta_zsh.sh; . ./script_zsh.sh; . ./script_zsh_2.sh
```

outputs

```
./meta_zsh.sh re-define s()
  calling s() ./script_zsh.sh
./meta_zsh.sh re-define s()
  calling s() ./script_zsh_2.sh
```

**The question is, how to achieve same effect in bash?**

I tried change to `${(%):-%x}` to `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` or `$0`, but neither works.

why bother?

After above meta_xx.sh sourced in ~/.zshrc (~/.bashrc),

*I can type `s` in the shell to reload a recently source script, 
if `meta_s` is in it.*

Comment: Maybe are you searching for `$FUNCNAME`...  `${FUNCNAME}` !?

Comment: Is it used to retrieve function's name, if that's the case, then no. My need is dynamically expand to script's name, not function's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BASH_SOURCE` is actually the stack of callers, with `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` being the current file, so you can use `${BASH_SOURCE[1]}`:

```
$ cat meta.sh 
meta_s() {
    eval 'CALLER=${BASH_SOURCE[1]}; echo "$CALLER re-define s()"; s() { echo " calling s() $CALLER"; }'
}
$ cat s1.sh 
meta_s
s
$ cat s2.sh 
meta_s
s
$ . meta.sh ; . s1.sh ; . s2.sh 
s1.sh re-define s()
 calling s() s1.sh
s2.sh re-define s()
 calling s() s2.sh
```